# cqlsh "Unable to connect to any servers" on Windows installation

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I installed Cassandra on Windows 10. When i trying to run cqlsh from /bin/,

I get the following error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': \
    error(10061, "Tried connecting to  [('127.0.0.1', 9042)].
Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine \
    actively refused it")})
```

I installed Cassandra from apache.org official site . also I get reference from
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-cassandra-on-windows - Everything is looks good from the reference.

can anyone help me to solve this ? thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure Cassandra is running? Do you see it in the process list?

Comment: Also, which C* version did you install? 3.11 or 4.0?

Comment: The last thing, provide the logs printed by Cassandra when you start it.

Comment: no, I can't see process list
and version of cassandra is 3.11.13 , version of java is i am using JDK 1.8

Comment: i am getting error only like which i already Share with you

Comment: You see a `cqlsh` error, which could happen for many different reasons.

You don't see the process list by itself or you don't see Cassandra there? What's the output when you execute `cassandra` command from the step 4 of the instructions you follow? Do you keep the terminal with running Cassandra open when you trying to connect? 

NOTICE: "Do not close the current cmd session."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that `cqlsh` can't connect to the local Cassandra instance. The default configuration in `conf/cassandra.yaml` is for Cassandra to listen for CQL clients on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) and CQL port `9042`:

```
native_transport_port: 9042
rpc_address: localhost
```

Since you're getting a "connection refused" error, the most likely issue is that Cassandra is not running on your Windows machine. Check the Cassandra logs (usually in `logs/system.log`) for errors which would provide clues as to why Cassandra couldn't start.

As a side note, there is very limited Windows support in Cassandra 3.x and there are several known issues that will not be fixed due to limitations in the operating system.

Furthermore, Windows support has been completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 due to lack of maintainers and testing ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

As a workaround, we recommend the following:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy [K8ssandra.io](https://k8ssandra.io/get-started/)

If you just want to build apps with Cassandra as a backend, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier that lets you launch a Cassandra cluster in a few clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!

Comment: thanks, Erick this is really helpful for me ,
and also thanks , for edit this Question and show in proper format...again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you keep this terminal open and Cassandra runs when you are trying to connect? Notice you have to launch `cqlsh` from a different terminal window.

[image: Instructions step 4]

Please check the steps again, mostly probably Cassandra simply doesn't run. Keep attention on the p.4 specially.